# Formatar resultado para dias, horas e minutos no SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Senhores, bom dia.
Preciso trazer em uma consulta SQL, em um campo formatado como DD:HH:MM:SS, onde o campo em si o valor é decimal, Ex:

Valor: 720,5659

Resultado que espero: 30:00:33:50
30 dias, 0 horas, 33 minutos e 50 segundos

```
DECLARE @MINUTES decimal(7,4) = 720,5659
SELECT
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(COALESCE (@MINUTES, 0) / 24) AS VARCHAR (8)), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST (CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME, @MINUTES)/24,108) AS VARCHAR (8)), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(COALESCE (@MINUTES, 0) % 60) AS VARCHAR (2)), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR((@MINUTES* 60) % 60) AS VARCHAR (2)), 2);
```

Comment: ta dando erro? qual??

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: *"onde o campo em si o valor é decimal"* e que valor é esse? são minutos, segundos, horas???